# Dataframe Finding bigger values from previous row

Tags: python, pandas

How can I iterate and shift to the upper row to extract the value that is larger than the current row, but not the largest? For example, given a list of time-series data with price change of the day:

```
arr = np.array([
       -2.9 ,  1.21, -0.09,  1.43, -0.34, -1.45,  1.44, -3.05,  0.39,
        1.2 ,  0.96, -0.66,  0.93,  0.19, -2.37,  1.05, -0.47,  1.  ,
        1.25,  0.16,  0.16, -1.08,  0.91,  1.41,  0.26])

df_date = pd.DataFrame(data=arr, columns=['INDU-CHG%'])
```

I would like to retrieve the higher values from the past, as demonstrated in column "previous-hi" in the DataFrame below:

```
    INDU-CHG%   previous-hi
0   -2.90   []
1   1.21    []
2   -0.09   [1.21]
3   1.43    []
4   -0.34   [1.43]
5   -1.45   [-0.34]
6   1.44    []
7   -3.05   [1.44]
8   0.39    [1.44]
9   1.20    [1.44]
10  0.96    [1.2]
11  -0.66   [0.96]
12  0.93    [0.96]
13  0.19    [0.93]
14  -2.37   [0.19]
15  1.05    [1.2]
16  -0.47   [1.05]
17  1.00    [1.05]
18  1.25    [1.44]
19  0.16    [1.25]
20  0.16    [1.25]
21  -1.08   [0.16]
22  0.91    [1.25]
23  1.41    [1.44]
24  0.26    [1.41]
```

The code below demonstrates my non-Pandas implementation that is inefficient, performance-wise.

```
df_date['previous-hi'] = None
for index, row in df_date.iterrows():
    df_date['previous-hi'][index] = df_date[:index].where(df_date['INDU-CHG%'] > row['INDU-CHG%']).dropna().tail(1)['INDU-CHG%'].values
```

Edit: Is it possible to retrieve the index of the larger values as well? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.expanding`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.expanding.html) with custom function - filtered values by last, swap order and get `NaN`s if no matched value by `next` with `iter`:

```
def f(x):
    return next(iter(x[x > x[-1]][::-1]), np.nan)
```

Or use `if-else` statement:

```
def f(x):
    a = x[x > x[-1]]
    return a[-1] if len(a) > 0 else np.nan
```

---

```
df_date['previous-hi'] = df_date['INDU-CHG%'].expanding().apply(f, raw=True)
print (df_date)
    INDU-CHG%  previous-hi
0       -2.90          NaN
1        1.21          NaN
2       -0.09         1.21
3        1.43          NaN
4       -0.34         1.43
5       -1.45        -0.34
6        1.44          NaN
7       -3.05         1.44
8        0.39         1.44
9        1.20         1.44
10       0.96         1.20
11      -0.66         0.96
12       0.93         0.96
13       0.19         0.93
14      -2.37         0.19
15       1.05         1.20
16      -0.47         1.05
17       1.00         1.05
18       1.25         1.44
19       0.16         1.25
20       0.16         1.25
21      -1.08         0.16
22       0.91         1.25
23       1.41         1.44
24       0.26         1.41
```